# Logcat Console appears only in DDMS in ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-logcat

i had logcat, console etc showing in java portion of the ADT, one day i closed it, then it was not showing in the java portion of the ADT, i tried to open it as `window/show view/logcat`,but nothing happens,same happens with the case of console also, but i was able to open it up in DDMS using the same way. why it is not showing in JAVA? is there any fix for my issue, please help

Comment: Probably it's there, but minimized. Have you tried to search the Android-thingy icon all over the place?

Comment: as you said, if it is hidden? how to find it out?

Comment: @AndrewT. yes i did, but i dont know where it is hidden, please help

Comment: Well, I can't really help, since I can't reproduce it. Sorry.

Comment: @AndrewT. double click on the tab showing logcat, then it will form a seperate window. just close it.

Answer (score 0):

In my Eclipse, there are two LogCat views. One says "deprecated". Perhaps you're clicking on the deprecated one and it doesn't work at all on your box anymore?

[image: LogCat menu items]

Comment: yes there are two, and i am selecting the one which u have selected in the above image, still nothing happens